# Smallest number in a range [a,b] with maximum number of '1' in binary representation

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given a range [a,b] (both inclusive) I need to find the smallest number with the maximum number of '1's in binary representation. My current approach is I find the number of bits set in all numbers from a to b and keep track of the maximum.
However this is very slow, any faster method?

Comment: Have you tried accumulating x^2? I've never done the statistics and pattern math, but it sounds like it'd be relevant...
On that note, uncertain if this is more or less math exchange related

Comment: If you had to find the number between 1000 and 10000 with the most nines, you wouldn't loop from 1000 to 10000 and count the nines in each number, would you?

Comment: No, but it is more difficult in binary as it is made of only 0's and 1's

Comment: I realized my answer was incorrect, deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find most significant bit which is different in a and b. It will be 0 in a, 1 in b. If we place all other bits to the right to 1 - resulting number will be still in range [a; b]. And it will the single number with maximum number of ones in representation.

**EDIT**. The result of this algorithm always returns the number with n-1 bits set to one, where n is number of bits which can be changed. As pointed in comments - there is a bug in case if all of there n bits in b are set to 1. Here is the fixed code snippet:

```
int maximizeBits(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }
    int m = a ^ b, pow2 = 1; // MSB of m=a^b is bit that we need to find
    while (m > pow2) { // Set other bits to 0
        if ((m & pow2) != 0) {
            m ^= pow2;
        }
        pow2 <<= 1;
    }

    int res = a | (m - 1); // Now m is in form of 2^n and m - 1 would be mask of n-1 bits
    if ((res | b) <= b) { // Fix of problem if all n bits in b are set to 1
        res = b;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the loop in Jarlax' answer by a "parallel suffix OR", like this

```
uint32_t m = (a ^ b) >> 1;
m |= m >> 1;
m |= m >> 2;
m |= m >> 4;
m |= m >> 8;
m |= m >> 16;
uint32_t res = a | m;
if ((res | b) <= b)
    res = b;
return res;
```

It generalizes to different sizes integer, using ceil(log(k)) steps in general. The initial test `a == b` is not necessary, `a ^ b` would be zero, therefore `m` is zero, so nothing interesting happens anyway.

---

Alternatively, here's a completely different approach: keep changing the lowest 0 to a 1 until it is no longer possible.

```
unsigned x = a;
while (x < b) {
    unsigned newx = (x + 1) | x; // set lowest 0
    if (newx <= b)
        x = newx;
    else
        break;
}
return x;
```

Comment: Indeed your 2nd solution `while ( (a | (a + 1)) <= b ) { a |= a + 1; }` is equivalent to mine and much simpler.

Comment: @Jarlax hold on! What if `b` has the maximum number of bits set? Wouldn't it loop forever?

Comment: Good point, thanks! I've made silly bug, condition should look like this: `while (b - (a | (a + 1)) >= 0) { a |= a + 1; }`. Note that it will work only for signed integers. For unsigned your original solution is (I believe) the simplest.